Using React Three CSG and Fiber, how can I use an uploaded STL file as the source for a subtraction?
I want to upload two stl files, and create a subtraction against the first stl using the second.   When I upload a single stl and try to subtract using a Three based geometry it works well, but when I attempt to use the loaded stl, I simply get a blank scene.
In the example below,  I am trying to use the second loaded item inside the subtraction.  If you remove the reference to loaded geometry, and replace with a simply three built sphere geometry, you will see that it works.
    
    import React, { useState } from 'react'
    import { useRef } from 'react'
    import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber'
    import { Geometry, Base, Subtraction, Addition } from '@react-three/csg'
    import { STLLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/STLLoader'
    import { Environment } from './Environment'
    import { OrbitControls, PivotControls } from '@react-three/drei'
    import { BufferAttribute } from 'three'
    
    function App() {
      const [stlModel, setStlModel] = useState(null)
      const [stlModelB, setStlModelB] = useState(null)
    
      const handleFileChange = (event) => {
        const file = event.target.files[0]
        const reader = new FileReader(file)
    
        reader.onload = (e) => {
          const loader = new STLLoader()
          const geometry = loader.parse(e.target.result)
          setStlModel(geometry)
        }
    
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
      }
    
      const handleFileBChange = (event) => {
        const file = event.target.files[0]
        const reader = new FileReader(file)
    
        reader.onload = (e) => {
          const loader = new STLLoader()
          const geometry = loader.parse(e.target.result)
          setStlModelB(geometry)
        }
    
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
      }
    
      const ready = stlModel && stlModelB
    
      return (
        <div>
          {!ready && (
            <div>
              <input type="file" accept=".stl" onChange={handleFileChange} />
              <input type="file" accept=".stl" onChange={handleFileBChange} />
            </div>
          )}
    
          {ready && (
            <Canvas shadows camera={{ position: [-15, 10, 15], fov: 55 }}>
              {stlModel && (
                <>
                  <color attach="background" args={['skyblue']} />
                  <ModelRender geom={stlModel} geomB={stlModelB} />
                  <Environment />
                  <OrbitControls makeDefault />
                </>
              )}
            </Canvas>
          )}
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    function ModelRender({ geom, geomB }) {
      const csg = useRef()
      geom.setAttribute(`uv`, new BufferAttribute(new Float32Array([]), 1))
      return (
        <mesh receiveShadow castShadow rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} position={[0, -3, 0]} scale={[0.02, 0.02, 0.02]}>
          <Geometry useGroups ref={csg}>
            <Base geometry={geom}>
              <meshPhysicalMaterial color={`green`} />
            </Base>
            <PivotControls activeAxes={[true, true, true]} rotation={[0, Math.PI, 0]} scale={100} anchor={[0.4, 0, 0]} onDrag={() => csg.current.update()}>
              <Window geom={geomB} />
            </PivotControls>
          </Geometry>
        </mesh>
      )
    }
    
    function Window({ geom }) {
      const csg = useRef()
      geom.setAttribute(`uv`, new BufferAttribute(new Float32Array([]), 1))
      return (
        <Subtraction position={[50, 50, 50]}>
          <mesh receiveShadow castShadow rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} position={[0, -3, 0]} scale={[0.02, 0.02, 0.02]}>
            <Geometry useGroups ref={csg}>
              <Base geometry={geom}>
                <meshPhysicalMaterial color={`red`} />
              </Base>
            </Geometry>
          </mesh>
        </Subtraction>
      )
    }
    
    export default App
    


Suspect the problem is not with csg, but with STL. STL is not the best format for 3d graphics… You gonna need to provide code sandbox for that to be fixed :(…
